# update value of a cell located in another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, formula

On sheet1, I have:

Col. A | Col. B
Micha | New
Elisa | New

On sheet2, I have:

Col. A | Col. B
Micha | Paid
Elisa | Reserved

I would like that if in sheet2 the column B says "Paid", then it inputs "Paid" in sheet1 column B to the corresponding name.

Result:

Col. A | Col. B
Micha | Paid
Elisa | New

The goal is to not enter a formula in sheet1.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could a formula placed in cell B1, which would apply to all of column B, be used?  You say you do not want a formula in sheet1 but without a Google Apps Script item I see no other way to do this.

Comment: Well I basically have a status in this column with data validation, which means there is not only "new" and "paid" but also other statuses...

Comment: You will need custom [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) code for that.  I would suggest you may want to rethink the use case instead.  If you decide to go the custom code route, try to put something together and make anew post when you have questions.

Comment: Ok so there is no formula that can change the value of a cell which doesn't contain the said formula? How disappointing.. Then I'll try and find something else. Thanks Karl

Comment: You can use ARRAYFORMULA() to apply a formula to multiple connected cells ( a range), but you cannot place a manual value in any of the cells.  The formula must apply to that entire range.  To be able to have manual and calculated values you need custom script.